# Sql - How to make this query

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I am trying to make a query for **SQL Compact**

It is basically these queries, but I was hoping I could combine them into one.

1.

```
SELECT schoolId,opponent 
FROM TEAM_SCHEDULE
WHERE seasonId = " & i & "
AND gameid = " & currentGame & "
ORDER BY id"

These are variables, trying to eliminate them at some point
currentMatch(0) = schoolId
currentMatch(1) = opponent
```

2.

```
SELECT id
FROM player
WHERE school = " & currentMatch(0) & "
AND starter = 'TRUE'
AND game_id = " & currentGame & "
ORDER BY weight
```

3.

```
SELECT id
FROM player
WHERE school = " & currentMatch(1) & "
AND starter = 'TRUE'
AND game_id = " & currentGame & "
ORDER BY weight
```

I was thinking I could do something like this, but I ran into a problem trying to figure out how to add the two schools to the query.

```
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT b.id, player.id" &
                            " FROM player b" &
                            " WHERE player.school = " & currentMatch(0) &
                            " OR player.school = " & currentMatch(1) &
                            " INNER JOIN player" &
                            " ON b.weight = player.weight" &
                            " ORDER BY player.weight"
```

To hopefully clear up any confusion, I am trying to:

1. Select 2 schools(int) from team_schedule, schoolId and opponent.
2. Select all starters('True') at every weight from both of those schools.
3. Pair up the starters from each school according to weight.
4. Be able to select each pair and manipulate the data.

Appreciate any help!

This is the parsing error from your query Nikola,
[image: Error]

Comment: Argh!! String concatenation for sql values like that is evil.

Comment: Heh, most importantly I am trying to get my stuff to work. I tried setting up parameters before but I didn't have any luck. I will try it again once I get a handle on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be your query. You can state the same table more than once, but you need to provide different alias to each one. In this case player is listed twice as p1 and p2. Match on players weights is also done in join part, but it might be in where clause.

```
SELECT 
  schoolId,
  opponent, 
  p1.id Player1, 
  p1.Weight Player1Weight, 
  p2.id Player2, 
  p2.Weight Player2Weight
FROM TEAM_SCHEDULE
inner join player p1
   on TEAM_SCHEDULE.schoolId = p1.school
 and TEAM_SCHEDULE.GameID = p1.Game_id
 AND p1.starter = 'TRUE'
inner join player p2
   on TEAM_SCHEDULE.opponent = p2.school
  and TEAM_SCHEDULE.GameID = p2.Game_id
  AND p2.starter = 'TRUE'
-- tricky part - do weights match perfectly 
-- or do you need additional weight range table?
  AND p1.weight = p2.weight
WHERE TEAM_SCHEDULE.seasonId = " & i & "
AND TEAM_SCHEDULE.gameid = " & currentGame & "
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I have a parsing error when I try to use this query at "on **TEAM_SCHEDULE**.schoolId = p1.school" This might be a limitation of sql compact, not sure.

Comment: @Meowbits what the error says? I don't see an obvious error here.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my original question to show the error.

Comment: @Meowbits You put ",player" after first TEAM_SCHEDULE and glued together p1 and on.